# use webcam on a http website in google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, webcam.js

I am using **webcam.js** for getting a photo clicked of a customer for profile creation on my cloud based retail store software.

It used to work fine in earlier versions of chrome and is still working fine on firefox. But now latest version of chrome and even other browsers like Opera have started throwing errors on invoking webcam - **only https versions are allowed to use webcam.**

Its a personal use software and i don't want to **spend extra on a SSL certificate**. Is there some option where in we can add exception for a http site to use webcam

**Current Code:**

```
function loadCamera(){
        Webcam.attach( '#my_camera' );
        Webcam.set({
            width: 200,
            height: 200,
            dest_width: 200,
            dest_height: 200,
            force_flash : true
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check out letsencrypt or certbot (basically the same). They issue SSL certificates for free and the setup is very straightforward and easy.

Link:

https://letsencrypt.org/